# How to create a rolling linear regression in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to create (as the title suggests) a rolling linear regression equation on a set of data (daily returns of two variables, total of 257 observations for each, linked together by date, want to make the rolling window 100 observations). I have searched for rolling regression packages but I have not found one that works on my data. The two data pieces are stored within one data frame.

Also, I am pretty new to programming, so any advice would help.

Some of the code I have used is below.

```
    WeightedIMV_VIX_returns_combined_ID100896 <- left_join(ID100896_WeightedIMV_daily_returns, ID100896_VIX_daily_returns, by=c("Date"))
    head(WeightedIMV_VIX_returns_combined_ID100896, n=20)

plot(WeightedIMV_returns ~ VIX_returns, data = WeightedIMV_VIX_returns_combined_ID100896)#the data seems to be correlated enought to run a regression, doesnt matter which one you put first
ID100896.lm <- lm(WeightedIMV_returns ~ VIX_returns, data = WeightedIMV_VIX_returns_combined_ID100896)
summary(ID100896.lm)    #so the estimate Intercept is 1.2370, estimate Slope is 5.8266. 
termplot(ID100896.lm)
```

Again, sorry if this code is poor, or if I am missing any information that some of you may need to help. This is my first time on here! Just let me know what I can do better. Thanks!

Comment: If your objective is to get the rolling coefficients then using the builtin BOD data frame: `library(zoo); nr <- nrow(BOD); reg <- function(ix) coef(lm(demand ~ Time, BOD, subset = ix)); rollapplyr(1:nr, 3, reg, fill = NA)` .

Comment: This works great. Thanks so much @G.Grothendieck !